# How to turn multi-value image field into a UL

Tags: 7, theming

I have a multi-value image field.  I want to output the images in a UL/LI.  Should I add a prefix and suffix in preprocess_field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly do it with a preprocess function...or you could install the [Fences module](https://drupal.org/project/fences) and do it through the UI:

> Fences is a an easy-to-use tool to specify an HTML element for each field. This element choice will propagate everywhere the field is used, such as teasers, RSS feeds and Views. You don't have to keep re-configuring the same HTML element over and over again every time you display the field.

Comment: I didn't use Fences, as I'm using Display Suite, but your post led me to see how to do it in Display Suite.  With Display Suite extras, per that field set to expert, I was able to add classes and elements.